# Web scraping: How can I extract links from html that correspond to keywords being matched with other tags without the keyword in the url?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to extract job descriptions from a Webpage if it matches with certain Keywords and this works, however I also want to extract the link that corresponds to the description found in the HTML. The issue is that the link occurs before the described keywords and the URL does not include a keyword to search for. How can I extract the links that match the job description that was found through the keywords?

Here is my code:

```
import re, requests, time, os, csv, subprocess

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_jobs(url):

keywords = ["KI", "AI", "Big Data", "Data", "data", "big data", "Analytics", "analytics", "digitalisierung", "ML",
            "Machine Learning", "Daten", "Datenexperte", "Datensicherheitsexperte"]
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'}

html = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)

time.sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

jobs = soup.find_all('p',text=re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(keywords)))

# links = jobs.find_all('a')


jobs_found = []
for word in jobs:
    jobs_found.append(word)
with open("jobs.csv", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as toWrite:
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite)
    writer.writerows(jobs_found)
    # subprocess.call('./Autopilot3.py')
    print("Matched Jobs have been collected.")


get_jobs('https://www.auftrag.at//tenders.aspx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the web I have seen that the link is always two levels higher than the description. Then you cold use `find_parent()` function to obtain the `a` tag of the jobs found.

You have in your code:

```
jobs = soup.find_all('p',text=re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(keywords)))
```

Then after that add:

```
for i in jobs:
   print(i.find_parent('a').get('href'))
```

This will print the links. **Please note that these links are relative links not absolute**. You should add the root to find the specific page. For example, if you find that one link is: `ETender.aspx?id=ed60009c-8d64-4759-a722-872e21cf9ea7&action=show`. The you must add to the beginning: `https://www.auftrag.at/`. Being the final link: https://www.auftrag.at/ETender.aspx?id=ed60009c-8d64-4759-a722-872e21cf9ea7&action=show

If you want you can add them to a list as you do with the jobs descriptions. The full code (without saving in csv) would be:

```
import re, requests, time, os, csv, subprocess

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_jobs(url):

    keywords = ["KI", "AI", "Big Data", "Data", "data", "big data", "Analytics", "analytics", "digitalisierung", "ML",
                "Machine Learning", "Daten", "Datenexperte", "Datensicherheitsexperte"]
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'}

    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)

    time.sleep(2)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    jobs = soup.find_all('p',text=re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(keywords)))

    # links = jobs.find_all('a')


    jobs_found = []
    links = []
    for word in jobs:
        jobs_found.append(word)
        links.append(word.find_parent('a').get('href'))
    with open("jobs.csv", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as toWrite:
        writer = csv.writer(toWrite)
        writer.writerows(jobs_found)
        # subprocess.call('./Autopilot3.py')
        print("Matched Jobs have been collected.")

    return soup, jobs
soup, jobs = get_jobs('https://www.auftrag.at//tenders.aspx')
```

If you want to add the full url, just change the line:

```
links.append(word.find_parent('a').get('href'))
```

To:

```
links.append("//".join(["//".join(url.split("//")[:2]),word.find_parent('a').get('href')]))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for this! Where in the Code would I add the rest of the HTML? Would I then just iterate over the links and add "https://auftrag.at" to each link? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: If you want to obtain the full link, change the line where the links are appended to the link list to: `links.append("//".join(["//".join(url.split("//")[:2]),word.find_parent('a').get('href')]))`  It basically takes the root of the original url and appends the link obtained. I am going to edit the original answer for that matter.